# How to redirect to some component in Angular when the url has multiple variables concatenated with "&"?

Tags: angular, url-routing, angular-routing, payment

From the backend I get the following URL

http://localhost:4200/paypal/?paymentId=PAYID-L7LA6CT5K826252R&token=EC-1R8557872G&PayerID=8ANSA9QW

My target is it to redirect to the home component when this link occurs.

At the moment I am trying to do this with the angular routing module like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
  { path: 'PayPal/:paymentId&:token&:PayerID', component: HomeComponent}
];
```

How do I have to structure the route for redirecting to the component?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

no need to add these query parameters in the route path. you just need to have `paypal`. And in navigation just navigate by query parameters **like this**

**Routes**

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
  { path: 'paypal', component: HomeComponent}
];
```

**Navigation**

```js
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

export class AppComponent  {
  constructor(
     private router: Router,
     private activeRoute: ActivatedRoute
  ) { 
     this.router.navigate(['paypal'], { queryParams: {
       paymentId: 'PAYID-L7LA6CT5K826252R',
       token: 'EC-1R8557872G',
       PayerID: '8ANSA9QW'
     }});
  }

}
```

**Also, you can get these query parameters from the activated route like this**

```js
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

export class AppComponent  {

  constructor(
     private router: Router,
     private activeRoute: ActivatedRoute
  ) { 
   // get the params only one time
   console.log(activeRoute.snapshot.queryParams, 'paypal query params');

   // or you can subscribe the query param changes
   
   activeRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
         console.log(params, 'paypal query params from the subscription');
   })
  }

  
}
```